# ! LaTeX Error: File `moderncv.cls' not found

Tags: miktex, moderncv

I am trying to compile this simple file with the moderncv but I am getting the following error:

`! LaTeX Error: File moderncv.cls not found.`

Then I clicked program --> MiKTeX 2.9 --> Maintenance --> Upadte MikTeX
and after taking the default configuration and clicking nex I ma getting Sorry, but something wen wrong: HTTP Error ="HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"

So How can I solve this problem?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual} %[blue, green, orange, red, grey]
\let\makeletterfoot\makecvfoot
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm} %Laenge link
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: MiKTeX repo is currently down: http://miktex.org/alert/update-problem-5938. you may try a different mirror or wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not update MiKTeX right now, as there seems to be a mess with the `tools` package. I suppose the problem will be settled very soon.

In the meantime, if you need `moderncv`, you can proceed as follows: download from CTAN or one of its mirrors, in `/pub/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages` the file `moderncv.tar.lzma` + these 3 files: `pr.ini, miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma, miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma`, store them in some directory and launch MiKTeX Package Manager. Open the `Repository > Change Repository` menu, then install from the directory  containing the downloaded files.

**Added** (04-06): The problem has been solved. You can update regularly now

Comment: I just did an install on a home machine and am suffering the result.  When MikTeX comes back online, can you speculate on whether I will need to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Do you mean there's a mess  in your system, or you've only a missing `tools`? In the second case I 'd go to the simplest: uninstall and reinstall the package. It takes a rather long time reinstall  if you only have a basic install, plus selected packages (I speak from experience ;o)

Comment: In retrospect, I think all that might have been broken was auto-package download.  I guess I'll find out this evening when I try again to compile some sample code from this site (which I find uses all kind of packages I'm not inclined to use in my daily work).